# My project stopped working after cleaning build Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I tried cleaning solution then run build solution. After that visual studio says not responding. I forced close the application then clicked my project again just to see that opening any forms,running, cleaning solution, building solution makes visual studio not responding. clicking view code seems to be working.

I tried running other projects and it seems to be working fine. Does that mean my project currently working is corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by restarting my PC. It seems the project that I'm working on is still running in the background even though it's not showing on my screen. The project is now working fine again.

Comment: Your problem seemed off-topic since the first moment (= lack of understanding of your specific conditions which you didn't transmit properly to us) and your answer has confirmed this point. But proposing restarting the PC as a solution!! Come on! This is not serious (I personally use it as a joke with extremely clueless people). If you want this question/answer to be remotely useful to anyone else (= on-topic), you should share the specific details. For example: the previous project was still running because you did what; ideally you should also share the names of the processes.